# ResourceBundle and Properties file - using keys vs using values

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xhtml, richfaces, facelets

I have a `rich:select` which is like the `h:selectOneMenu` and am using `selectItems` to populate the drop-down menu from properties file (using `ResourceBundle`). Here is the problem , after populating the drop-down menu with the VALUES from the properties file and I try to submit the form I get `report_form:overtime_dropdown: Validation Error: Value is not valid` and the menu is cleared. OK, I know what that means, but the interesting part comes when I select something from the menu again and submit it. Then the form is submitted.. strange!?! If I am using the keys from the properties file to populate the drop-down everything works fine from the first time.
I am posting some of the related code below.

report.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"> 

<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ticket_style.css" />
</h:head> 
<h:body> 
    <rich:panel header="#{lang.reportPanelHeader}" id="panel">
        <h:form id="report_form">


                <span class="label">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.overtimeLabel}" />
                </span>
                <span class="input">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{validateReportAction.enabled}">
                        <f:ajax render="@this overtime_dropdown"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <rich:select styleClass="overtime" enableManualInput="false" 
                        defaultLabel="#{lang.defaultOvertimeLabel}"
                        disabled="#{!validateReportAction.enabled}"
                        id="overtime_dropdown"
                        value="#{validateReportAction.selectedOvertime}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{validateReportAction.timeSpentList}" />
                </rich:select>

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandButton value="#{lang.submitLabel}"/>

        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</h:body> 
</html>
```

population method getTimeSpentList() in ValidateReportAction class

```
public List<SelectItem> getTimeSpentList() {

        System.out.println("################################################# Test " + test++);

        timeSpentList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.time_intervals", context.getViewRoot().getLocale());

        Enumeration<String> time_interval_keys = bundle.getKeys();

        List<String> sortedValues = new ArrayList<String>();

        opositeOfProperties = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        while(time_interval_keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = time_interval_keys.nextElement();
            String value = bundle.getString(key);
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
            opositeOfProperties.put(value, key);
            sortedValues.add(value);
//          sortedValues.add(key);
        }

        Collections.sort(sortedValues, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (o1.charAt(1) != ' ') {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o2.charAt(1) != ' ') {
                    return 1;
                }

                return o1.compareTo(o2); 
            }
        });
        for (String value : sortedValues) {
            timeSpentList.add(new SelectItem(value));
        }

        if (timeSpentList == null || timeSpentList.isEmpty()) {
            timeSpentList.add(new SelectItem(""));
            return timeSpentList;
        }
        return timeSpentList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Found the problem... because the Locale is BG (from Bulgaria) properties file for that locale is called and there are some values wrote in Bulgarian and somehow that makes the mess.